# get user entered value in google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to use Google Analytics in my application. I had read online documents for this. And I got idea (Not clear) how to use it. I just want to know whether it is possible to display user entered value in google anayltics.

Suppose I have a registration form and in this form i am collecting information of user address. I want to know number of particular customer from particular city. (This city field had been entered by user at the of filling registration form). If yes it is possible to collect user enter information in Google analytics will you please let me know how to get this?

Thanks in advance. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say user subit the form by clicking mTrackerButton :

```
 mTrackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SendEventGoogleAnalytics("FormEvent", "cityName",
                        variableNameYouWantToSend);
            }
 });
```

Below are the api you need to place in activity

```
 private void InitGoogleAnalytics() {
        mGoogleHelper = new GoogleAnalyticsHelper();
        mGoogleHelper.init(MainActivity.this);
    }

    private void SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics() {

        mGoogleHelper.SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics("MainActivity", MainActivity.this);
    }

    private void SendEventGoogleAnalytics(String iCategoryId, String iActionId, String iLabelId) {

        mGoogleHelper.SendEventGoogleAnalytics(MainActivity.this, iCategoryId, iActionId, iLabelId);
    }
```